# How to supply a generic component with a more concerete component for rendering in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a side panel in my application to display a number of different views. It is basically a core extension of the UI in order to supply real estate for interacting with things as an aside.  My panel is essentially a "Sheet" according to [Material Design spec](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-side.html), but it is built custom by me.  The goal is to be able to change what UI gets rendered in this Panel depending on the source of the event that triggers the panel to open.  Since in Angular all "views" are really just Components it feels like I need to pass in a Component object somehow and tell my Panel to simply render the component as-is.  I don't want this view change to be related to the URL/routing in any way. I looked around a little and could not find a way to do this which makes me think my idea is bad and there is a better way to do this.

Has anyone dealt with a similar scenario that knows of a clean way to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of solutions:

1. Use an [aux](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes#multiple-outlets) router configuration. Basically you can just change the path of the secondary router-outlet to make it render any component you want.
2. Another simple way to accomplish this is to use the [*ngComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet).

Basically you have a service or a `@Input()` which provides the component which needs to be rendered, and in the side panels template you can then have this in your template:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="renderComponent"></ng-container>
```

And in your side panel:

```
@Component({})
export class SidePanelComponent {
  @Input()
  renderComponent?: Type<any>;
}
```

This is very basic, obviously, but you get the idea. Don't forget to add the component you want to be rendered to the `entryComponents`.

3. A third way is to use the [dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). Where the documentation speaks for itself :) This is a bit more complicated though